# FIle.ReadAllText old file content?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to read the text content of a file using File.ReadAllText.

For some reason, when I run the application from Visual Studio, our while the .exe is in the Debug\bin folder, it works fine, reading the current content, but when I move the .exe elsewhere and run it, it reads old content of the file. That is, text that used to be in the file, but has later been changed.

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
string winFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
string text = File.ReadAllText(winFolderPath + @"\file.ini");
```

What's the deal with that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: what file path you are using? please add some code example

Comment: Just wait I try to see your code in my crystal ball.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using a relative filename to specify the file to read?  That could explain why moving the exe would result in different file content.  Of course, you'd have to move the exe to a directory that held a file with the same name...

Comment: My bad guys, hope my edit will help a bit.

Comment: @LanceAurora I failed to reproduce your problem. do you cache the content somewhere in your code?

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not this particular piece of code. That will always read the contents of "C:\Windows\file.ini" (on your average machine where the Windows folder is indeed "C:\Windows"). So unless by "moving the .exe elsewhere" you mean "moving it to a different machine", it's not the problem. Conceivably, you could also be tripped up by UAC virtualization -- this is where Windows pretends you successfully accessed a system folder, but you really didn't, because you aren't an administrator. Don't use "C:\Windows" to store application-specific files.

Comment: Combining paths like that will get you into trouble. I suggest using Path.Combine for this.

Comment: @Old Fox no, there's barely any other code than that, at the moment.

Comment: @Mihai Caracostea I just did actually, also tried StreamReader instead. Still no luck

Comment: I didn't mean it would solve this problem it was a general recommendation.

Comment: I suggest you run your exe as an administrator and prepare to be amazed.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert the use of C:\Windows wasn't my idea, but what I have to use.

Comment: @Mihai Caracostea That was it, of course. Thanks guys.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was your idea. I meant to imply that whoever thought it up was a bad person. I had almost forgotten about UAC virtualization because only bad people run into trouble with it. :-)

Comment: @Jeroen And people who have to maintain legacy code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAC Virtualization emulates working with special folders just for the sake of legacy applications. In reality, unless you run in elevated context, you cannot touch those folders.